# Does mental incapacity imply physical incapacity?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, physicalism

If someone is mentally incapable of doing something, does that also mean they are physically incapable of doing it? My argument is that since the brain is a physical and material object, assuming that it alone is responsible for thought, and that its influence on the body is absolute, can't we assume that any shortcomings it has be described in terms of a physical incapacity?

Comment: "its influence on the body is absolute" is too strong, as I read it. The brain does influence the body, and pretty strongly, but still your doctor can test your reflexes just by hitting you below the knee. Or, fun with electricity, so on.

Comment: Regarding "psysical incapacity", some brain dysfunctions are of that kind. In particular those that are due to physical trauma. But even in such cases the brain has such tremendous flexibility & learning ability that it in time can some times / often work around the problem. Another problem with using this term for "any shortcoming", is that most problems are due just to psychological things, problems of the mind, which are states/configurations of the brain. That's akin to how software and data are states/configurations of a computer. E.g. you can't physically see an image in the electronics.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf For the "its influence...is absolute" quote, remember that this question is about mental -> physical, so if I am mentally unable to move my leg, then I am physically unable to move it, at least without the aid of some external phenomena like electricity, etc.

Comment: In otherwords, "can a mental incapacity always be directly related to a physical incapacity?" And if not, in what situation is there a mental incapacity which does not have a physical counterpart?

Comment: Also, gaining an ability over time is akin to filling a balloon with air, which only explodes after a certain point defined by complex physical laws.

Comment: Consider, a soldier, around in WW1 or 2, had his limbs ripped off by a shell, but **still capable** of mentally doing something, though in agony, might be able to shoot machineguns or throwing grenades. ( There were many cases ). You sound like Hegel.A Materialist.

Comment: So according to you, for example, taking the above soldiers' case, had he had his or her limbs ripped off, he would be **still capable of doing philosophy or playing music etc etc.** Since according to you, the **brain-the-material** seems to be the source of controlling the physical structure below the brain. Though I **do not** completely deny your premise.

Comment: I can see that some people are getting offended by this question. This was not my intention. However, I have not seen a valid argument against it. @Kentaro Not sure what your point is. I didn't say anything about "physical imparement -> mental imparement", as it obviously doesn't work that way.

Comment: Yes, I took it a bit an offense. But according to your **If someone is mentally incapable of doing something, does that also mean they are physically incapable of doing it?**, so that, I asked such a question. Since if I understand precisely, the brain-the-material is the engine to work the system-body under, therefore, I could assume if a soldier's limbs were cut off, but the brain-the-substance order to dance, he would sure be happy to dance. My point is, I wanted to ask, isn't it vice versa?

Comment: But as I said, I do not deny your premise. Sure, I have seen a person whose brain was damaged and have been in bed for years. But I think it is not the **only way** how the body ( as a whole ) the material works.

Comment: @Kentaro Think of it like a river with two dams. If the upstream dam is closed, then the downstream dam is essentially useless because there is no water (opening/closing has no effect). But if the downstream dam is closed, the upstream dam still has an ability to affect the state of the water. From one side of the downstream dam, it would seem like the upstream dam has no effect. This river flows from head to body in my opinion.

Comment: I think this is a stronger question than the downvotes and close votes suggest, but perhaps you could put it in some sort of context to help out?  What kinds of cases of incapacity would hang on the implication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If someone is mentally incapable of doing something, does that also mean they are physically incapable of doing it?

Mental activities are not of the same kind as physical activities. In other words, *everyone* is physically incapable of activity that is mental, and mentally incapable of activity that is physical.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Not sure why it was marked as off-topic. Sorry to everyone who was offended.